# How to create and fire a collection of Consumers<T> in java for an event listener pattern

Tags: java, events

I'm trying to create a pretty standard event listener/broadcast system. Just playing around with different ideas right now to see how they work in our domain.

The problem I'm having is I can't seem to find the correct syntax for actually calling the Consumer with generics.

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<Class<? extends Event>, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<? extends Event>>> listeners;

public <T extends Event> void listen(Consumer<T> consumer, Class<T> clazz){
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<? extends Event>> consumers = listeners.get(clazz);
    if (consumers == null) {
        consumers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        listeners.put(clazz, consumers);
    }
    consumers.add(consumer);
}

public <T extends Event> void fire(T eventToFire, Class<T> clazz){
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<? extends Event>> consumers = listeners.get(clazz);
    if(consumers != null){
        consumers.forEach(x -> x.accept(eventToFire));// <-- This blows up saying that Consumer expects type T, but I'm passing it ? extends Event
    }
}
```

What's the correct way to get be able to call it, or am I stuck with having to use object for ConcurrentLinkedQueue? I tried suppress warnings, but this seems to be a deeper issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the compiler doesn't know that you made sure in your `listen` method that both the key and value of the map are parametrized by the same `T`.  For all it knows, the two types that are both `? extends Event` may not be compatible with each other.

The only way to fix this is with an explicit cast:

```
consumers.stream()
        .map(c -> (Consumer<T>)c )
        .forEach(c -> c.accept(eventToFire));
```

On another note, the `listen` method can be rewritten as:

```
listeners.computeIfAbsent(clazz, x -> new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>())
                .add(consumer);
```

Not only is that shorter, it's thread-safe unlike explicitly checking for null.

Also, the `fire` method doesn't need to take `Class<T>` as a parameter.  You can use `listeners.get(eventToFire.getClass())`