# How to use generic collections with typed parameters in a generic map with wildcards (Java)

Tags: java, events, generics

This question is related to [How to create and fire a collection of Consumers<T> in java for an event listener pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482417/how-to-create-and-fire-a-collection-of-consumerst-in-java-for-an-event-listene/29482739#29482739). I was trying to use a collection of events to help batch operations up, but so far I can't seem to come up with the correct configuration of generic definitions to work.

Here is my code so far.

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<Class<? extends Event>, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<? extends Event>>>> listeners;

public <T extends Event> void listen(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<Collection<T>> consumer){
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<T>>> consumers = listeners.get(clazz);
    if (consumers == null) {
        consumers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        listeners.put(clazz, consumers); // Complains that consumers is not the type Collection<? extends Event>
    }
    consumers.add(consumer);
}

public <T extends Event> void fire(Collection<T> eventToFire){
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<? extends Event>>> consumers = listeners.get(eventToFire.getClass());
    if(consumers != null){
        consumers.forEach(x -> x.accept(eventToFire));
    }
}
```

I've tried setting `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<T>>> consumers = listeners.get(clazz);` to be `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<? extends Event>>> consumers = listeners.get(clazz);` but then it complains that the `consumers.add(consumer);` is not the type `Consumer<Collection<T>>`.

No casting seems to be getting around this, with the exception of `consumers.add((Consumer<Collection<? extends Event>>)(Object)consumer);`, but this just looks horrible to me, and it seems like I must be missing something, or messing something up, because it doesn't seem like this should be a required step.

Comment: Your problem here: In your `listen` method you require the type parameter of `Class` and the type parameter of `Collection` to be the same. In the corresponding parts of the type of `listeners` you don't do the same (Both `?`s could be of any type as long as they extend `Event` - even of different types). To impose the same restrictions as in the `listen` method you'd need to add a type parameter to the class containing that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the compiler to know that if the key is of type `Class<T>` (where `T extends Event`), then the value is a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<T>>>`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to express this fact. However, you know it's true because the only key/value pairs you ever put into the map have that form. Therefore it's safe to put in the cast, but I would also include a comment explaining why it's ok.

The type of the values should actually be

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<? extends Consumer<? extends Collection<? extends Event>>>
```

not

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<? extends Event>>>
```

The latter is a queue of `Consumers` that must be able to accept a collection of *any* type extending `Event`, but you only want a `Consumer` that accepts `Collections` of *some specific type* `T` extending `Event`. It's *incredibly* difficult to understand this, but just remember that you usually need `? extends` at every level when you mix wildcards with nested type parameters.

Finally, `eventToFire.getClass()` isn't what you want as this returns the class of some collection type, whereas your keys are of type `Class<? extends Event>`. Due to type erasure, you cannot get the type parameter from a collection at runtime, so you will need to explicitly pass `clazz` to `fire` as well.

With these changes the code becomes

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<Class<? extends Event>, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<? extends Consumer<? extends Collection<? extends Event>>>> listeners;

public <T extends Event> void listen(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<Collection<T>> consumer){
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<T>>> consumers = (ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<T>>>) listeners.get(clazz);
    if (consumers == null) {
        consumers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        listeners.put(clazz, consumers);
    }
    consumers.add(consumer);
}

public <T extends Event> void fire(Class<T> clazz, Collection<T> eventToFire){
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<T>>> consumers = (ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Consumer<Collection<T>>>) listeners.get(clazz);
    if(consumers != null){
        consumers.forEach(x -> x.accept(eventToFire));
    }
}
```

The only casts required are in the two lines that assume the key and value match, but this is the best you can possibly do.

Comment: Thanks, the getClass() was from the earlier code that only accepted one event at a time, I had forgotten to change it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's pretty much how it works.  Java's type system can't express the constraint you're trying to express.  Your wrapper implementation is type-safe, but the compiler can't prove it, so you'll have to do dirty unsafe casts to convince the compiler you know what you're doing.